# Bitwise XOR operator and byte arrays

Tags: java, arrays, bitwise-operators, bitwise-xor

I have the following piece of code:

```
byte[] S = new byte[256];
byte[] T = new byte[256];

for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
    S[i] = (byte)i;
    T[i] = 13;
}

int j = 0;
int i2 = 0;
while (i2 < 256) {
    j = j + S[i2] + T[i2] & 255;
    byte[] arrby = S;
    int n2 = i2;
    arrby[n2] = (byte)(arrby[n2] ^ S[j]);
    byte[] arrby2 = S;
    int n3 = j;
    arrby2[n3] = (byte)(arrby2[n3] ^ S[i2]);
    byte[] arrby3 = S;
    int n4 = i2++;
    arrby3[n4] = (byte)(arrby3[n4] ^ S[j]);
}
```

The S[] array with the initial values: 0,1,2,3,4,5...

When the program reach the line:

```
arrby[n2] = (byte)(arrby[n2] ^ S[j]);
```

S[0] changes its value from '0' to '13' and I can't understand why. 
What is modifying the S[0] value? As I see it the '^' is just doing a comparison and changing the value of arrby[n2] but not of S[0]

Comment: `byte[] arrby = S;` - `S` and `arrby` refer to the same array.

Comment: Beyond that: your names are kinda horrible. They don't say anything about what the variables are about. It is also pretty horrible to "spell out" the length of your arrays (255) all over the place. Better use theArray.length, or at least SOME_CONSTANT = 255 instead.

Comment: `byte[] arrby = S` - This does **not** create a copy of `S` and store it into `arrby`. It copies the reference, which means that both variables will refer to the same object. If you modify `arrby` you'll modify `S` too, and viceversa.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here:

```
byte[] arrby = S;
```

You are making `arrby` *point* to the *same* array as S.

Then:

```
arrby[n2] = (byte)(arrby[n2] ^ S[j]);
```

You are changing an entry in that array.

Tada ...

So, the solution is: if you don't want to modify the content of your array, make sure that you don't create *other* references pointing to that array. Depending on your requirements, you could for example **copy** the data from S into a freshly created `arrby` array first.

Answer (score 1):

The line of code below makes `arrby` refference the same allocated memory as `S`

```
byte[] arrby = S;
```